# mysql set filter select without filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
id  name  salary  year

1   A     100     2013
2   B      88     2012
3   C      95     2010
4   A      45     2012
5   B      87     2011
6   C      98     2011
7   A      54     2009
```

I want to select all records but show sum of salary for last two years(2013, 2012) only for each name? But the following query would give sum for all years.

```
select name, sum(salary) as total from table group by name;
```

Output should be:

```
name  total
A     145
B     88
C     0
```

Note: I know using where clause would get that but i want all names to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why don't you want to use `WHERE` clause. Anyway, MySQL supports inline `IF` statement.

```
SELECT  Name,
        SUM(IF(year IN (2013,2012), salary, 0)) total
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e645/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦═══════╗
║ NAME ║ TOTAL ║
╠══════╬═══════╣
║ A    ║   145 ║
║ B    ║    88 ║
║ C    ║     0 ║
╚══════╩═══════╝
```

---

if you want to be more RDBMS friendly, you can use `CASE`

```
SELECT  Name,
        SUM(CASE WHEN year IN (2013,2012) THEN salary ELSE 0 END) total
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY Name
```

Comment: That's lightening fast.. thank you. I need this solution in SphinxQL and it worked thanks.